# Replace js path using unix sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

Good evening everybody.
I'm trying to replace paths at `*.js` files using unix sed script. So, I wrote correct regex expression and sed does not fall, but I can not get a correct result.

**UPD:** I'm using macOS

Incoming string: `import * as module from "/test"`

My regex:

```
 \s\*import(.+)from\s+\['\\"\](\\/.+)[^\n]+
```

that found a path pattern and returns two groups I needed (`* as module` and `/test.js`)

For example I need to change `import \* as module from "/test"` as  `import \* as module from "/myFolder/test.js"`

So, but my bash command

```
echo 'import * as module from "/test.js"' |
sed -r "s:\s*import(.+)from\s+['\"](\/.+)[^\n]+:import \1 from \"\/myFolder\2\":g "
```

returns the original string! Could you help please, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gnu-sed`:

```sh
s='import * as module from "/test.js"'
sed -E "s~\\b(import.+ from )(['\"])([^'\"]+)\2~\1\2/myFolder\3\2~g" <<< "$s"

import * as module from "/myFolder/test.js"
```

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `\\b`: Match a word boundary
- `(import.+ from )`: Match string starting from word `import` followed by 1+ of any character followed by word `from` surrounded with space on both sides
- `(['\"])`: Match a `'` or `"` as opening quote and capture in group #2
- `([^'\"]+)`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a quote and capture in group #3
- `\2`: Match same quote as the opening quote

---

On OSX use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E "s~(import.+ from )(['\"])([^'\"]+)~\1\2/myFolder\3~g" <<< "$s"
```

Comment: Looks like it does not work at macOS...

Comment: Are you trying it on OSX? Your question has `sed -r` which is used in gnu awk

Comment: Updated answer for OSX

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
s='import * as module from "/test.js"'
echo "$s" | awk '/^import.*from[[:space:]]+"\//{sub(/\//,"/myFolder&")} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Following is the detailed explanation for above code.

- Creating a variable named `s` which has all the values as input for `awk` program in it.
- Printing it by `echo` command and passing it as a standard input to `awk` program here.
- In `awk` program checking condition if a line satisfies `^import.*from[[:space:]]+"\/` regex(which basically checks if line starts from import till from followed by space(s) followed by "/) if this is TRUE then following action will happen.
- using `sub` function of `awk` to perform substitution to substitute `/` with `/myFolder/` as per requirement.
- Then mentioning `1` is a way to print current line in `awk`.